# .htaccess HTTPS Redirect while keeping the URL shortform

Tags: .htaccess

Ok I have this Rewrite Rule in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^settings https://%{HTTP_HOST}/user_settings.php
```

This redirects "http://domain.com/settings" to "https://domain.com/user_settings.php".

How do I make it so that it redirects "http://domain.com/settings" to "https://domain.com/settings"? Meaning, how can I redirect a url from HTTP to HTTPS while still keeping the Redirect Short url in .htcaccess?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Updating answer after question was clarified.

You can do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^settings(/?)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^settings(/?)$ /user_settings.php [L,NC]
```

The first `RewriteCond` will check if HTTPS is off and the following `RewriteRule` will only happen if it is.

The first `RewriteRule` will match either of the following:

- `http://domain.com/settings`
- `http://domain.com/settings/`

The `(/?)` allows the trailing forward slash to be optional. The `R` in `[R,NC]` forced this to be a redirect, the `NC` means it's not case-sensitive.

The second `RewriteCond` will again check HTTPS, but this time to make sure it's on.

If HTTPS is on, and you're at your directory (meaning, the first rewrite was successful), it will then do a rewrite to `user_settings.php`. The `L` in `[L,NC]` means that if this rule is matched, it's the last `RewriteRule` it should follow.

Comment: But how does it know to use user_settings.php as a redirect? This will only give a 404 error.

Comment: Are you wanting `http://domain.com/settings` to redirect to `https://domain.com/user_settings.php` but display `https://domain.com/settings` in the URL?